# How to get data from firebase ( datasnapshot)?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database and I had stored the user information in the database ( realtime ) and I want to get the information into my user profile UI in my app
Now when I use snapshot, I don't know how to get the information of it
Any help please?

```
        val userId = authRef.currentUser?.uid
        val currentUser = dataRef.getReference("/Users/$userId")
        currentUser.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
//    I need to get data from here ( userDisplayName , userPhone, userCity, userCountry)
        }

        })
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the JSON data at `/Users/$userId` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please respond with @.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 val userId = authRef.currentUser?.uid
    val currentUser = dataRef.getReference
    val userchild = currentuser.child("Users").child("userId")
    userchild.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val userDisplayName = p0.child("userDisplayName").getValue(String::class.java)
    val userPhone = p0.child("userPhone").getValue(String::class.java)
    val userCity = p0.child("userCity").getValue(String::class.java)


    }

    })
```

Must type exect spellings of Users, UserId and other childs. and To these values to textview in the Ui add

```
 TextView.setText=variable abc
```

Your Mistakes in codes.You have not taken correct data snapshot which i have updated.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the data try the following:

```
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
//    I need to get data from here ( userDisplayName , userPhone, userCity, userCountry)
        val userDisplayName = p0.child("userDisplayName").getValue(String::class.java)
        val userPhone = p0.child("userPhone").getValue(String::class.java)
        val userCity = p0.child("userCity").getValue(String::class.java)

        }

        })
```

Comment: shall I use
addValueEventListener   or 
addChildEventListener   or 
addListenerForSingleValueEvent 
??? 
to retrive the user details??

Comment: use addListenerForSingleValueEvent as it will retrieve only once and not keep listening for changes